# opencart how to display all categories with images on home page opencart 1.5.1.3

Tags: php, jquery, opencart

in opencart 1.5.1.3 i want to display all  categories with images at top and  category name at botoom.

once any one click on image or name will goto that category page.

i am trying my best,
even i have featured.tpl file, which is showing featured products on home page, i also try to modify it but its not working.

in featured.tpl i try to change

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
```

but this is not working and displaying error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

how can i display that?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't just use $categories in the tpl file, you have to assign the categories to the view using the controller

Open

> /catalog/controller/module/featured.php

Find this line around line 10

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

Before it put

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$this->data['categories'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
```

And save

Comment: Thanks and its working but not displaying images of category. is there any thing else i need to do ?

Comment: @air - How have you tried to display the image exactly? You will need to at least use $category['image']